# Customize sidebar button image in split-view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, splitview, swiftui-navigationview

I have a SwiftUI app. On iPad, the sidebar icon (top-left) appears when split-view is active.

[image: iPad showing a sidebar on the left, and the main content on the right. A sidebar image shows in the top-left, which I want to change.]

I can't hide it using `.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)` to make my own custom one.

How can I fix this?

Code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("Sidebar")
            
            Text("Main content")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not ideal, but I am now using my own custom version of the sidebar by using an HStack and some extra stuff (to make it slide, etc)