# Toggle Sidebar in Code using SwiftUI NavigationView on iPad

Tags: swift, swiftui, ipados

I'm trying to utilize the **built-in sidebar** from **SwiftUI 2.0** by using **NavigationView** like this:

```
NavigationView {
   MainView()
   ListView()
   DetailView()
}.navigationBarHidden(true)
```

But since I want to use my own **Custom Back Button**, I've hidden the NavigationBar and tried to **toggle the sidebar with code** which doesn't work.

```
self.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
```

I've already seen a lot of solutions for **macOS**:

```
NSApp.keyWindow?.firstResponder?.tryToPerform(#selector(NSSplitViewController.toggleSidebar(_:)), with: nil)
```

But I can't seem to find equivalent for **iPad**, thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem, link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63971289/9607863). In the end I just decided to make my own custom sidebar, which isn't ideal, but the best solution for me.

Comment: Thanks, I might as well implement it on my own if I still haven't gotten any solution next week.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @NitricWare I didn't, no

Answer (score 4):

I used this code to change the default sidebar settings:

```
extension UISplitViewController {
    open override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.preferredDisplayMode = .secondaryOnly
        self.preferredSplitBehavior = .overlay
    }
}
```

*self* exposes several sidebar methods and properties that can be used. I hope it will be useful!

Answer (score 0):

So this is not a good long term solution but if you are like me and 100% needed the native approach to work here's how it can be hacked. Using https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect you can find the right view controller in the hierarchy and set the display mode.

```
Text("Some View").introspectViewController { vc in
    guard let splitVC = vc.parent?.parent as? UISplitViewController else {
        return
    }

    splitVC.preferredDisplayMode = .oneBesideSecondary
}
```

This is **BRITTLE** but it works.